# Issues with a college assignment using Python

Tags: python

Im and MSc student who has been lumped with doing python code this year but have no prior experience. I was wondering if someone could help me with this question, i have some parts done.

Q6)

Assignment 6
Grades are classified according to % (ranging from 0 to 100 inclusive), if greater than or equal to the following:-
70 First ; 60 Second Upper ; 50 Second Lower ; 45 Third ; 40 Pass; 0 Fail.
Create a dictionary from the data above, and use it as part of a program to grade marks, from 2 sources:-
1. during development, grade marks in sequence from a hardcoded list of marks = [-1,0,1,49,60,71,100,101],
2. after development, include code to repeatedly request marks for testing, until terminated by entering q or Q.
Marks will be awarded for concise coding, which should run efficiently with minimal use of comparisons tests.
Retain features to take input from both sources above in the final code, i.e. don't delete item '1' after development.

My solution so far looks something like this :

```
hardcoded_lst = [-1,0,1,49,60,71,100,101]
grade_input=int(input('What grade?')
input_lst= []
while grade_input != 
     input_lst.append(grade_input)
     grade_input=int(input('What grade?')
print(input_lst)
```

i need to create a dictionary for the values but currently that isnt working either.

Id appreciate any help, in basic code as i am not very advanced.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you read standard python documentation? Do you know how to create a python dictionary? What part of creating dictionaries do you need help with?

Comment: I have read through all the notes we were given but it didnt give much on how to create a dictionary or to itterate a list over it. I have something like this, (but it doesnt work)

d = {<0:'Invalid',
     <40:'Fail',
     <45:'Pass',
     <50:'Third',
     <60:'Second Lower',
     <70:'Second Upper',
     >70:'First',
     >100: 'Invalid'}

Comment: The first thing you should do before asking a question, is to read some documentation. Python documentation on dictionaries is very thorough. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries and https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I suggest you change your title to something like *"why doesn't a dictionary accept a key like <0?"*, or whatever your actual problem is, which would be stated clearly in the question and just in not the comments. If you just say you know nothing about dictionaries and want someone to teach you, you'll only be redirected to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program should do as you asked. There are several lines that are commented out with the `#` character. You may uncomment those lines if you wish to see the value of the variable referenced in the call to the `debug` function. Please take time to study the code so that you understand how and why it works.

```
import pprint
import sys

RANGE = range(0, 101)
GRADE = {70: 'First', 60: 'Second Upper',
         50: 'Second Lower', 45: 'Third',
         40: 'Pass', 0: 'Fail'}
MARKS = -1, 0, 1, 49, 60, 71, 100, 101


def main():
    """Grade hardcoded marks and grade marks entered by the user."""
    # debug('MARKS')
    grade_all(MARKS)
    grade_all(get_marks())
    print('Goodbye!')


def grade_all(marks):
    """Take an iterable of marks and grade each one individually."""
    for mark in marks:
        # debug('mark')
        if mark in RANGE:
            print(mark, 'gets a grade of', grade_one(mark))
        else:
            print(mark, 'is not a valid mark')


def grade_one(mark):
    """Find the correct grade for a mark while checking for errors."""
    # debug('RANGE')
    if mark in RANGE:
        for score, grade in sorted(GRADE.items(), reverse=True):
            if mark >= score:
                return grade
    raise ValueError(mark)


def get_marks():
    """Create a generator yielding marks until the user is finished."""
    while True:
        try:
            text = input('Mark: ')
        except EOFError:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            # debug('text')
            if text.upper() == 'Q':
                break
            try:
                mark = round(float(text))
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter a mark')
            else:
                # debug('mark')
                if mark in RANGE:
                    yield mark
                else:
                    print('Marks must be in', RANGE)


def debug(name):
    """Take the name of a variable and report its current status."""
    frame, (head, *tail) = sys._getframe(1), name.split('.')
    for scope, space in ('local', frame.f_locals), ('global', frame.f_globals):
        if head in space:
            value = space[head]
            break
    else:
        raise NameError('name {!r} is not defined'.format(head))
    for attr in tail:
        value = getattr(value, attr)
    print('{} {} {} = {}'.format(
        scope, type(value).__name__, name, pprint.pformat(value)), flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

creating dictionary isn't that tough, its as simple as creating list, which you have already done

For list

```
  mylist = []
  #for dictionary
  mydictionary = {}
```

Adding item into dictionary

```
  mylist.append(value)
  mydictionary["fail"] = 50
```

Iterating the list

```
 for item in mylist:
     print item
```

Iterating in dictionary

```
 for key,value in mydictionary.iteritem():
     print key,value
```

I hope this helps you, there might be mistake in iteritem spelling etc you could google it but thats how its done normally

here is updated thing

```
 mydictionary = {}

 marks = 0

 mydictionary[(0,45)] = "Fail"
 mydictionary[(46,59)] = "Lower"
 mydictionary[(60,69)] = "Second Lower"
 mydictionary[(70,100)] = "First"

 marks = 63

 for key,value in mydictionary.iteritems():
     if marks >= key[0] and marks <= key[1]:
         print value
```

The given code works you could also do it in this way though

Comment: Good answer to get the OP started in the right direction. - Though I'm not sure, what his dictionary should look like, i.e. 50 -> "fail", "fail" -> 50, or maybe (50,60)->"fail".

Comment: you could ask what you don't understand, i might be able to elaborate further.

Comment: So i understand how to create a list from a user input values (and how to print this list). However since the quit function is Q the list prints the numbers in ' ' so have to convert these to int in order to iterate over a dictionary. Then the actually formation of the dictionary, it doesnt seem to accept < or > as boundaries.......(im sure this is super basic but thanks for helping)

Comment: Hanno bind is right you should do () here is just a working sample you can run it in new file and checkout how it is working, i have updated my answer with updated code that might be helpful for you

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a dictionary using the grade values as keys, and depending on the input populate  the key with the input, or reject it as invalid. Maybe something like this:

```
if input>=70:
  grade[first]=input
elif input>=60 and input<70:
  grade[secondupper]=input



elif input<0 or input>100:
  print 'invalid grade!'
```

If you have more than one value for each grade then consider using a list to read the values into, and then setting the corresonding dictionarty value to the list as you fill it.

Comment: That's probably just what the OP is *not* supposed to do.

Comment: Other than not stating what the variables 'first' and 'secondupper' hold, you seem to be modifying the grade dictionary. More importantly, your approach to the problem is wrong because it requires minimal use of comparison tests.

Comment: Fair point re minimal comparison tests. I think I misunderstood OP re what the dictionary is supposed to achieve. Sorry OP.